# SQL/PowerBI search in a particular line (not row) of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, dax

I have a column with multiple line data. It shows as one line in SQL Server but multiple lines in Power BI so I guess there are some special characters in there to tell Power BI where the new line starts.

[image]

What I want to achieve is to search the second to the last line instead the whole cell, to find out whether it contains for example the key word "christchurch" in it.

Is there anyway that I can achieve this in SQL Server or Poewr BI? Thanks.

Comment: Does it matter if you search the entire cell? For example, if the solution always has you finding `christchurch`, is that still acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In power BI:

```
Contains = 
var index = 
    SEARCH(UNICHAR(13), [YourColumn], , 0) + 1 
RETURN 
    SEARCH("christchurch", [YourColumn], index, 0)
```

This measure will return the starting index of the word "christchurch" (searches only after first newline char) and return 0 if not found.

**Note:** You might also want to try **UNICHAR(10)** or other special characters that might be used for a line break in your data.

Comment: Thanks Pratik, this looks promising, will give it a go

Comment: @Penn A little correction in the note: it's unichar(10) not 13

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` to scan through the text in an `nvarchar` or similar field. I don't really have your table structure, or a lot of sample data, but given what you have told me, the following should work:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Txt,
    CASE
        WHEN TRIM(UPPER(TXT)) LIKE '%CHRISTCHURCH%' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Has_ChristChurch

FROM
    tblFoo
```

[Here is a SQL FIDDLE for a live demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/80b0854/1)

Comment: Hi Jerry, this is great for searching the whole cell, but what if i want to search only the second to the last line?

Comment: We have a town called Blenheim, and there is a street called Blenheim street in Christchurch, they are in different cities, and there are plenty of other similar situations, so yes, it would be great if i can only search from a particular line